# pass data to object of uiviewcontroller on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone app with a tableviewcontroller.  When you click a certain cell it opens a new uiviewcontroller with this code:

```
 nextViewController = [[avTouchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"avTouchViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The uiviewcontroller above called avTouchViewController has a property that looks like:

```
IBOutlet SomeObject *controller;
```

SomeObject is an object with all relevant view properties.

I would like to pass an nsstring parameter from the tableviewcontroller I initialize the avTouchViewController with to someObject.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question; you say you're creating your `avTouchViewController`s when a cell is tapped inside an existing `UITableView`, but your last part describes the inverse situation.

Basically, if you want to pass information to a view controller, just give it a property that can be set (which may already be the case), e.g.:

```
nextViewController = [[avTouchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"avTouchViewController" bundle:nil];
nextViewController.controller = theInstanceOfSomeObjectIWantToPass;
```

You also may want to rename your `controller` property. To a reader, it doesn't make sense that a view controller has a property called `controller` which is actually a `SomeObject*`. As well, your class names should be capitalized, i.e. use `AvTouchViewController` instead of `avTouchViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would add my own initializer to my UIViewController subclass:

```
- (id)initWithController:(NSString *pController) {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"avTouchViewController" bundle:nil]) {
        self.controller = pController;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then just call the following (in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: or whereever):

```
NSString *controller = @"Sample String";

AVTouchViewController *nextViewController = [[AVTouchViewController alloc] initWithController:controller];
[controller release];

[self.navigationController pushModalViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
[nextViewController release];
```

As a point of style, class names conventionally begin with uppercase letters (hence my change to AVTouchViewController).

Comment: I used to prefer this method myself (coming from a strong C++ background and not liking the Cocoa requirement for all classes to have default constructors), but I stopped using it a few months ago. I think it's better that Cocoa code read more like a Cocoa developer would expect. That includes using default inits, and using parameters to set values.